# JavaFX Get ComboBox from ChoiceDialog

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a `javafx.scene.control.ChoiceDialog` object in my JavaFX project.  When the dialog opens, I want to set the focus to the underlying `ComboBox`.  However, I can't figure out how to get the underlying `ComboBox` control.  With a `TextInputDialog`, there is a method called `getEditor()`.  Is there any way (other than reflectively accessing the private `comboBox` member) to get the underlying `ComboBox`?

Comment: AFAIK, the ComboBox receives the focus by default when the ChoiceDialog is visible.

Comment: On Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64, running JRE 8u77 x64, I am seeing the initial focus on the default button (which happens to be the "OK" button).  I see the same behavior for `TextInputDialog`.  Have you observed different behavior on another OS/JVM combination?

Comment: I do not think that is possible. If you check the code for ChoiceDialog, the [constructor calls updateGrid()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u/rt/file/105417e52ffe/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceDialog.java#l151) which intern sets the [focus on the ComboBox](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u/rt/file/105417e52ffe/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceDialog.java#l220).

Comment: The problem with `requestFocus()` is that it only works once the stage is shown.  `Platform.runLater()` simply "post[s] the Runnable to an event queue and then return[s] immediately to the caller".  Then the Runnable is executed when the main application thread becomes available and has finished processing all previously queued tasks.  The problem is that the main thread becomes available prior to the dialog being shown, so the call to `requestFocus` is being executed too early.  Therefore, that line is an effective no-op, and the focus still remains on the default button.

Comment: From the documentation for [`Node.requestFocus()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus--): "*To be eligible to receive the focus, the node must be part of a scene, it and all of its ancestors must be visible, and it must not be disabled.*"

Comment: Your explanation makes sense but it is very difficult to say anything without a verifiable example. Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question. It will help us find what exactly might be going wrong in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the focus to the `ComboBox` you can use a dirty hack, which triggers `updateGrid` of the `ChoiceDialog` after it is shown:

```java
ChoiceDialog<String> choiceDialog = new ChoiceDialog<>("test", getData());
choiceDialog.showingProperty().addListener((ov, b, b1) -> {
    if (b1) {
        choiceDialog.setContentText("");
    }else {
        choiceDialog.setContentText(null);
    }

    //or 
    if (b1) {
        Node comboBox = choiceDialog.getDialogPane().lookup(".combo-box");
        comboBox.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

---

Obtaining the `ComboBox` instance using the style class is useful to override the default keyboard navigation:

```
final var options = (ComboBox) getDialogPane().lookup( ".combo-box" );
options.setOnKeyPressed( ( event ) -> {
  // When the user presses the down arrow, open the drop-down. This prevents
  // navigating to the cancel button.
  if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN && !options.isShowing() ) {
    options.show();
    event.consume();
  }
} );
```

When the above changes in place, pressing the down arrow key will open the combo box instance instead of navigating to the Cancel button.

Comment: How did you figure out the ".combo-box" constant?  I would like to know so I can look it up myself in the future.

Comment: It is the default Style class for `ComboBox`. You can get the Style class of a `Node` from the [CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) or you can use [Scenicview](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to inspect properties of the `Scenegraph`

Comment: Jeff, also look at `modena.css`, which is located inside `jfxrt.jar` in your JRE directory.  The modena stylesheet defines default styling for all controls.  If you are customizing the styling of existing controls, doing CSS lookups based upon their structure or just want to learn best practices for JavaFX CSS definitions, modena.css is an invaluable resource.